# How to configure routing to serve cshtml pages in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I am building a website that is 99% content (.cshtml files) and I'd like to set up MVC routing so that whenever I add a `new-page.cshtml` to a `folder` in my website it becomes available at `http://localhost:50000/folder/new-page` i.e. very similar to serving static files but with Razor goodies.

- Do I need MVC for that?
- If so, how do I configure the routing and the controller? I'd rather not have to add a new controller/route for every page.
- If not, what's the best way of achieving this static-like behaviour?

Comment: You are looking literally for [Razor pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/).

Comment: app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

Comment: @poke Thanks. I was looking and not seeing. I was led astray by the magical formula `routes.MapRoute("default","{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");` which is part of the app template. "Surely that won't work," thought I. "There is no controller named `new-page`, only a .cshtml file with that name." I still have no clue how it works but it does, thanks.

Comment: That’s because MVC is still set up in the razor page template even if you are not using it. Your project can generally have both razor pages and controllers/views content.